# Pass Javascript "document.write" values to hidden form submit value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that sets `document.write` values to a webpage that works fine, what I am trying to do is set the `document.write` values "also" to a `hidden` `html` field for submission form.

Here is what i have tried and cannot seem to get it to work:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

 <script language="javascript">
  document.forms('SendPasswordForm').GeoCity.value=geoplugin_city();
 </script>

<form id="SendPasswordForm" action="#" method="POST">

 <input type="hidden" name="GeoCity" value="">

</form>

<script language="Javascript">document.write(" "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_region()+", "+geoplugin_countryCode()); </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the second script tag below `form` tag as the script to update `GeoCity` field cannot find the field as it was declared afterwards.

You can find the updated code below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

<form id="SendPasswordForm" action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="GeoCity" name="GeoCity" value="">
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    document.forms['SendPasswordForm'].GeoCity.value = geoplugin_city();
</script>

<script language="Javascript">
    document.write(" " + geoplugin_city() + ", " + geoplugin_region() + ", " + geoplugin_countryCode());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery for this. jQuery significantly simplifies operations like this where plain JavaScript can be troublesome. jQuery takes just a few minutes to add to your project.

It can be downloaded by right-clicking *Download the compressed, production jQuery 3.2.1* -> Save As ... from this link:
http://jquery.com/download/

Then simply include it in your html- file:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/>
```

With jQuery included, all you need to do to change the value of your hidden field is:

1. Give your item an ID such as:

   ```
   <input id="HiddenInputID" type="hidden" name="GeoCity" value="">
   ```
2. Then change the value like this:

   ```
   $('#HiddenInputID').val('My new value');
   ```

I have made this working example- code: https://jsfiddle.net/09uwg5zq/